# Linkedin Messaging API

Tags: linkedin-api

I would like to get access to an API key to read messages from my personal Linkedin account, but I am not sure how I can get access.

Having researched this, I found this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/communications/messages?context=linkedin%2Fcompliance%2Fcontext&source=docs), but after contacting customer support, I am not sure if this is only available for businesses. Can someone explain me if it is possible to get an API key for the purpose described above?

Comment: Do you have a LinkedIn developer account?  Have you created a new application to obtain API credentials?  Start here:  https://developer.linkedin.com/